# Merging sublists based on content overlap, python 3

Tags: python, algorithm, list, array-merge

If we have a number of lists that contain sublists(pairs) with integers in them. If any two sublists have the same number, we want to merge them and erase the duplicate digit.

for example:
`alist = [[2, 1], [5, 3], [5, 1], [3, 4], [3, 1], [5, 4], [4, 1], [5, 2], [4, 2]]
becomes alist = [1,2,3,4,5]`
And the result would be all of them merge to one list because they happen to be all share digits in common.

but not all lists will be so convenient:
    `alist = [[4,5],[7,8],[6,7],[9,5]]`
    would become: `alist = [[4,5,9],[6,7,8]]`
The issue is I'm iterating over huge lists, with 10^7 entries in them.
Is there a method to complete this without two nested loops? that is what I am doing currently.

Comment: What happens when each element is a pair is contained in a different list?  IE: `[[1,2], [3,4], [1,3]]`, does this result in `[[1,2,3], [3,4]]` or `[[1,2], [1,3,4]]` or `[[1,2,3], [1,3,4]]`?

Comment: What is the range of values?

Comment: The digits in each pair can range as high as the total number of pairs, so digits <= the # of pairs, approx 10^7.

Comment: At the moment. all of the pairs are stored in one over arching list when I recieve them. But I could handle the input differently if there was good reason too. For example, I know deques are faster, but the operations that can be performed on them are more limited.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can recognise which pairs share a member by creating a hash table indexed by number whose entries are sets of pairs.

You can now view the problem as finding the connected components (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) in a graph where the nodes are pairs and two pairs are connected if they share a number. As the Wikipedia entry notes, you can do this by using depth first search to visit all of the nodes in the graph, using the depth first search to follow all of the direct and indirect links from a node to all of the other nodes in the same component. Another approach would be to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure to maintain sets of pairs, merging sets when two pairs from previously different sets share a number.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I lacked the language to adequately describe my problem before. I didn't really know this was graph theory. It is not a domain I have explored before, but now that I know where to start, I can do some reading to figure out my problem. I'll post back here when I've come to a solution. Cheers